# nhibernate transform result in a dictionnary

Tags: nhibernate

Hello
I would like how to have a specific output in nhibernate

```
var hql = @"select t1.info1, t2.info2
                    from table1 t1
                    left outer join t1.table2 t2";
var variable = session.CreateQuery(hql).List();
```

That query return an object array which contains another array.
ie : in the first line, info1 can be retrieved by variable[0][0]
and in the same line, info2 can be retrieved by variable[0][1]

I know that I can create a new Class like

```
class SpecificQuery
{
  public int info1;
  public int? info2
}

and then call :

session.CreateQuery(hql)
.SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(SpecificQuery))).List();
```

But I don't want to create a specific class each time I want to have a special return.

Does someone know a solution to that problem ?
For example, a IList< Dictionnary< string, object>>[]
In this case, the first line of info1 can be retrieve by variable0 (in case of variable[0][0]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the AliasToEntityMapResultTranformer

```
session.CreateQuery(hql)
   .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap).List();
```

This will return a list of IDictionary objects.

Answer (score 4):

NHibernate offers the Tuple class that could be used here:

```
var hql = @"select t1.info1 as First, t2.info2 as Second
                from table1 t1
                left outer join t1.table2 t2";

// instead of Tuple<String, decimal> you can use other types of course
var variable = session.CreateQuery(hql)
        .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(
             typeof(NHibernate.Linq.Tuple<String, decimal>)))
        .List<NHibernate.Linq.Tuple<String, decimal>>();
```

You would then access the items with

```
variable[0].First
variable[0].Second
```